# Wordpress - Show selected category from drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to show a list of my categories in a drop down on Wordpress using:

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); ?>
```

But using jQuery i'm trying to make the page display all categories, then when one is selected from the drop down menu hide all but the selected category.

Does anyone have an ideas?

Comment: I would recommend you to add some code and possibly a jsfiddle link

Comment: why do you need to hide the other categories, if you can only select one category does it really matter. is it for aesthetics. what if the user changes their mind later on and wants to select another category, then what

Comment: @gwillie imagine a long page of posts, like up coming events. But the user does not want to scroll through the list to find one they like, nor do they want to switch pages by selecting a category. Imagine if they could just select the category from a drop down at the top of the page, that would limit the posts on the page to just that category for example 'Christmas Specials'. They would switch by simply selecting another category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<?php   
    $arr = get_categories();
    echo "<select name='categorylist'>";
    foreach($arr as $option){
        echo "<option value='{$option}'>{$option->name}</option>";   
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: This looks awesome, but i can't seem to get it to work properly as i'm using a custom taxonomy 'events_categories'. I've tried `$arr = get_categories('taxonomy=events_categories');`